# Obtaining Solution Name in ToolWindow of VSpackage

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, envdte, vspackage

I'm new to Visual Studio Extensibility Framework to use VSPackage Extension. I want to obtain a DTE Object inside the user-control which is called inside MyToolWindow class.

I tried all the below possibilities:

1.`EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");
string solutionPath=dte2.Solution.FullName;`

The above trial gives only SolutionPath of the 1st instance of the visual studio which is opened. 
For EX: If Math1.sln and Math2.sln is opened,only Math1.sln path is assigned to solutionPath.

1. From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165322%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) link, "this.GetService" cannot be recognized in the button1.click (Am I missing any thing here)

Once, DTE object is obtained I shall be easily be able to obtain solution Name of the current instance.

I must be able to obtain appropriate  EnvDTE80.DTE object inside the click of the button which is inside User-control. This User-Control is called inside MyToolWindow.cs

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0")` is problematic because it will just give you a `DTE` of a random Visual Studio instance. You can obtain correct instance of `DTE` through the `GetService` call.
Then just enumerate the `DTE.Solution.Properties`, one of the properties should be the solution name. Probably `DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("Name")`, though I cannot check this at the moment.

As for your "GetService cannot be recognized", method is defined on an `IServiceProvider` which `ToolWindowPane` implements. If you want to use that in your control, you should pass the tool window instance to your control. Example:

```
public class MyToolWindow: ToolWindowPane {
    void SomeMethod() {
        var myControl = new MyControl(this);
    }
}

public class MyControl: UserControl {
    public MyControl(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        // Now you can call serviceProvider.GetService
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patko for the reply.

Comment: I implemented this and having a strange problem... I created one project with a custom window, this uses this solution mentioned. Then I created another one without the use of DTE. When the second one opens the debugger crashes on the var myControl = line of the former project. Although it is closed in a different directory shares no files, namespace, nor class name. The former (dte) above project is not running in anyway and is not deployed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have an abstract VsPackage class I use within all my home-brewed extensions; and I obtain the application instance this way...

```
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

public abstract class VsPackage : Package
{
    ...

    protected DTE2 GetApplication()
    {
        return this.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2; 
    }

    ...
}
```